# How to pass an array input variable to create multiple relationships?

Tags: neo4j-graphql-js

I am trying to pass an array to form multiple relationships from a node I am creating to multiple other nodes. So far, I am only using the default resolvers created by the neo4j graphql library.

More specifically, I am trying to pass an array "broaderConceptsV" which is an array of objects in the form [{uid1: ___ , name1: ___ }, {uid2: ___ , name2: ___ }, ... ] while creating a new concept node to create multiple IS_NARROWER relationships to other existing concept nodes.

The set-up below works if there is only one object in the broaderConceptsV array, but if the broaderConceptsV array is empty it creates an IS_NARROWER relationship to every existing node, and if the broaderConceptsV array has multiple objects, no relationships are created but the new concept node is still created.

Any help is appreciated! I think the issue lies in how the **AND:** variable in the **ConceptWhere** input, but I do not understand how I would loop through the array if I input it differently.

**Edit: Changing out "AND:" for "OR:" fixed the multiple object case, but passing an empty array still forms a connection with every existing node**

This is my schema:

```
    const typeDefs = gql`
  type Concept {
    uid: ID!
    name: String!
    block: String!
    addedBy: String!
    methodVideos: [Video!]! @relationship(type: "IS_METHOD", direction: IN, properties: "IsMethod")
    interestVideos: [Video!]! @relationship(type: "IS_INTEREST", direction: IN)
    narrowerConcepts: [Concept!]! @relationship(type: "IS_NARROWER", direction: OUT)
    broaderConcepts: [Concept!]! @relationship(type: "IS_NARROWER", direction: IN)
  }
```

This is the mutation I was trying to get working:

```
const ADD_CONCEPT = gql`
    mutation AddConcept(
      $uid: ID!
      $name: String!
      $block: String!
      $addedBy: String!
      $broaderConcepts: [ConceptWhere!]
    ) {
      createConcepts(
        input: [
          {
            uid: $uid
            name: $name
            block: $block
            addedBy: $addedBy
            broaderConcepts: { connect: { where: { node: { AND: $broaderConcepts } } } }
          }
        ]
      ) {
        concepts {
          uid
          name
          block
          addedBy
        }
      }
    }
  `;
```

This is the how I set up createConcepts:

```
createConcepts({
      variables: {
        uid: uuidv4(),
        name: nameRef.current.value,
        block: blockV,
        addedBy: user.uid,
        broaderConcepts: broaderConceptsV,
      },
```

Some relevant pieces from the augmented schema as seen in the Apollo client:

```
type Mutation {
  createConcepts(input: [ConceptCreateInput!]!): CreateConceptsMutationResponse!
}


input ConceptCreateInput {
  uid: ID!
  name: String!
  block: String!
  addedBy: String!
  methodVideos: ConceptMethodVideosFieldInput
  interestVideos: ConceptInterestVideosFieldInput
  narrowerConcepts: ConceptNarrowerConceptsFieldInput
  broaderConcepts: ConceptBroaderConceptsFieldInput
}



input ConceptBroaderConceptsFieldInput {
  create: [ConceptBroaderConceptsCreateFieldInput!]
  connect: [ConceptBroaderConceptsConnectFieldInput!]
}



input ConceptBroaderConceptsConnectFieldInput {
  where: ConceptConnectWhere
  connect: [ConceptConnectInput!]
}


input ConceptConnectWhere {
  node: ConceptWhere!
}



input ConceptConnectInput {
  methodVideos: [ConceptMethodVideosConnectFieldInput!]
  interestVideos: [ConceptInterestVideosConnectFieldInput!]
  narrowerConcepts: [ConceptNarrowerConceptsConnectFieldInput!]
  broaderConcepts: [ConceptBroaderConceptsConnectFieldInput!]
}


input ConceptWhere {
  OR: [ConceptWhere!]
  AND: [ConceptWhere!]
  uid: ID
  uid_NOT: ID
  uid_IN: [ID!]
  uid_NOT_IN: [ID!]
  uid_CONTAINS: ID
  uid_NOT_CONTAINS: ID
  uid_STARTS_WITH: ID
  uid_NOT_STARTS_WITH: ID
  uid_ENDS_WITH: ID
  uid_NOT_ENDS_WITH: ID
  name: String
  name_NOT: String
  name_IN: [String!]
  name_NOT_IN: [String!]
  name_CONTAINS: String
  name_NOT_CONTAINS: String
  name_STARTS_WITH: String
  name_NOT_STARTS_WITH: String
  name_ENDS_WITH: String
  name_NOT_ENDS_WITH: String
  block: String
  block_NOT: String
  block_IN: [String!]
  block_NOT_IN: [String!]
  block_CONTAINS: String
  block_NOT_CONTAINS: String
  block_STARTS_WITH: String
  block_NOT_STARTS_WITH: String
  block_ENDS_WITH: String
  block_NOT_ENDS_WITH: String
  addedBy: String
  addedBy_NOT: String
  addedBy_IN: [String!]
  addedBy_NOT_IN: [String!]
  addedBy_CONTAINS: String
  addedBy_NOT_CONTAINS: String
  addedBy_STARTS_WITH: String
  addedBy_NOT_STARTS_WITH: String
  addedBy_ENDS_WITH: String
  addedBy_NOT_ENDS_WITH: String
  methodVideos: VideoWhere @deprecated(reason: "Use `methodVideos_SOME` instead.")
  methodVideos_NOT: VideoWhere @deprecated(reason: "Use `methodVideos_NONE` instead.")
  methodVideosAggregate: ConceptMethodVideosAggregateInput
```